# Not all date data shows on x axis line chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am working with a line chart I am trying to get the dates to show on the x axis. It should be shown monthly. I am getting two months to show up but not 3. The first month (august) is not displaying on the x axis yet there is data plotted. Can someone help me?

This is the time_stamp being passed through.

Comment: can you share your current output? or better if you create a `https://codesandbox.io/` demo

Comment: @webcoder just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

its better you provide a sample in codesandbox, or maybe try this:

```js
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
   autoSkip: true,
   maxTicksLimit: 5
  },
  scaleLabel: {
  display: true,
  labelString:[ `Issues: ${yAxisCreatedIssues.length} created and ${resolvedNumber.length} resolved. Period: last 90 days (grouped daily)`]  ,
  },
  type: 'time',
  time: {
  parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  unit: 'month',
  displayFormats: { month: 'MMM-YYYY'}
        }
  },
],
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to work, I will try and make a codsandbox for you

Comment: I have created a codesandbox https://et571.csb.app/

Comment: updated the sandbox for you [demo] (https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-monad-q7h2w?file=/src/App.js) you forgot `bounds: "ticks",`

Comment: Thanks! hHow would I be able to remove the November date? I tried changing the max ticks to 3 and 4 and I am getting two Aug-2020 displaying with a max tick of 3 and if I implement a max tick of 4 I get the september value but two duplicate august values.

Comment: chart.js is sometimes crazy, but you can limit it using momentjs: `ticks: {
                  autoSkip: true,
                  maxTicksLimit: 3,
                  callback: (value) => {
                    const moments = timestamp.map((d) => moment(d));
                    const maxDate = moment.max(moments);

                    if (moment(value) < maxDate) {
                      return value;
                    }
                  }
                },`

Comment: Would you mind please updating it in the coding sandbox? I seem to be getting errors.

Comment: actually I did it! but there is white space in the end of the graph now?

Comment: you just need to specify ` distribution: "series",`, updated your sandbox [demo] (https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-mountain-k7h1s?file=/src/App.js), if it solves your problem pleas mark the answer as correct

Comment: thanks! Yeah it works, but its just that the duplicate value is still showing for the august month again

Comment: because it is daily, you can remove DD from parser like" ` parser: "YYYY-MM"`